# What is really the point of ViewBag?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag

In an ideal 'hello world' one should pass a *strongly typed* model back to the *view*.

```
return View(MyModel);
```

If things get sticky, we can create a

*ViewModel*

```
return View(MyViewModel);
```

ex.

**MyViewModel**

1. MyModel
2. Foo

I can avoid creating the whole *ViewModel*

and use a *ViewBag* in part.

```
ViewBag.Foo = Foo;
return View(MyModel);
```

I realize I will lose some *strongly typed* functionality

(ex. Intellisense)

in my View for that ViewBag.

Is this approach sloppy? against what MVC stands for?

**If so, what is really the point of ViewBag?**

Comment: It's for the things you forgot to put in your view model ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most useful use-case that I know of is out-of-band data like a message that might be shown on every page. An action filter could add that message to the ViewBag conditionally. You probably don't want to modify every view model class to hold that unrelated message because it might be a cross-cutting concern. An example of such a message/widget would be Stack Overflows outage announcements.

I do not recommend using ViewBag *instead* of a view model. The model class approach has the typical static typing advantages at the small cost of writing a class.

Comment: Very interesting, makes for sense now. Thanks!

Comment: I never seen `Stack Overflows outage` before :)

Comment: You don't remember that famous SO Outage on Thurs Oc 10 that took place from 12:02:00:01AM - 12:02:00:02AM? @Murali

Comment: I thought it was a delay from our proxy server. But i dont see the message, since the page itself was not loaded :(

Comment: They sometimes announce short read-only periods when they maintain the databases.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question, personally, I don't really think there is any point - all it does is encourage "lazy" coding. `dynamic` objects have their uses, however, I don't see the `ViewBag` as being one of them, I would much rather use `ViewData[]`/`ViewModel` and get my type-safety in there, especially when I *know* what types I am dealing with.

Comment: viewdata isnt really any more typesafe

Answer (score 1):

I haven't encountered a scenario where it was beneficial to use ViewBag over the alternative (a correctly structured view model). Some of the other answers mention using it for a piece of data that needs to be displayed on every page. In this scenario you should create a base ViewModel class that all of your ViewModels inherit from. I use this structure to store the logged in user, etc.

In my opinion ViewBag serves one purpose: to make it easy and quick to give a product demo of ASP.NET MVC while writing minimal code. It is not the best way to structure code, but it sells the product.